# Epsilon delta proof $\lim_{x\to 3}\sqrt{3-x}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I want to give an epsilon delta proof that$$\lim_{x\to 3-}\sqrt{3-x}=0$$

This means I want to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that$$3-\delta<\left|x-3\right|<3$$ implies that $$\left|\sqrt{3-x}\right|<\epsilon$$

Usually my rough work would start of by doing something like $$\left|\sqrt{3-x}\right|=\frac{\left|3-x\right|}{\sqrt{3-x}}$$

and then say that's less than something else. I can't really do that in this case though because the denominator gets infinitely small. How can I get past this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Choose any $\delta(\epsilon) < \epsilon^2$.

Comment: Use the fact that $a^2 < b^2$ implies that $a <b$ for positive $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Since you are taking the limit from below, you actually want to say *"... there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $3-\delta <x<3$ implies ..."* or equivalently *"... there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $0 < 3-x < \delta$ implies ..."*

Comment: Note you are looking at one sided limit $x \rightarrow 3^-$. Which means $x-3 < 0$. Now for any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $0 \leq \delta(\epsilon) < \epsilon^2$,  such that $-\delta(\epsilon) < x-3 < 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $|\sqrt{x-3}| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, since it is a left-hand limit, what you have to show is that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $3 - \delta < x < 3$ implies $|\sqrt{3-x}| < \epsilon$. Note that since $\sqrt{3-x} \geq 0$ for all $x \leq 3$ we have $|\sqrt{3-x}| = \sqrt{3-x}$. So, let's drop the absolute value.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. To figure out what to choose for $\delta$ let's square both sides of $\sqrt{3-x} < \epsilon$ getting $3-x < \epsilon^2$. This suggests letting $\delta = \epsilon^2$. With that choice of $\delta$ assume

$$3-\delta < x < 3.$$

This implies that $3 - \epsilon^2 < x$ and so $3 - x < \epsilon^2$. Taking the nonnegative square root of each side (which is ok on the left because $x < 3$) we get $\sqrt{3-x} < \epsilon$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I always forget the simplest things like squaring both sides lol.